# wrong output when getting two columns of a table with linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

i have this function in a class

```
    public System.Collections.IList cpv_No_Date_list()
    {
        var cpvNoDateList = (from s in context.DB.CPVs
                             select new { s.cpv_no, s.cpv_date} ).ToList();
        return cpvNoDateList;
    }
```

then i am calling this function and giving it as a source to a drop down list

```
        var Service = IOC.Get<IEntityListService>();
        var cpvNoDateSrc = Service.cpv_No_Date_list();

        cpvDrpdwn.DataSource = cpvNoDateSrc;
        cpvDrpdwn.DataBind();
```

function is collecting exact data from table but the problem is that it is not presenting it correctly.
Output in dropdown list is like this:

```
{cpv_no = 5, cpv_date = 1/2/2013}
{cpv_no = 7, cpv_date = 5/2/2013}
{cpv_no = 8, cpv_date = 8/2/2013}
```

How to get rid of these brackets in output???

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the default `ToString` method for an annoymous class

Create a new class and override ToString

```
public class CpvNoAndDate
{
  public int cpv_no  { get; set; }
  public DateTime cpv_date { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("cpv_no = {0}, cpv_date = {1}", cpv_no, cpv_date);
  }
}
```

Then project to your new class like this:

```
public System.Collections.IList cpv_No_Date_list()
    {
        var cpvNoDateList = (from s in context.DB.CPVs
                             select new CpvNoAndDate 
                             { 
                               cpv_no = s.cpv_no, 
                               cpv_date = s.cpv_date
                             }).ToList();
        return cpvNoDateList;
    }
```